# how to hide/show children tree react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to create a tree with a list I have ... I was able to display it in the correct order on the screen with the following code:

```
let TreeView = (props) => {
  let { data } = props;

  return (
    <div className="treeview-root">
      <header>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter project name" />
        <button className="btn-assets">Assets List</button>
      </header>
      <article>
        <ul>
          <Tree data={data} />
        </ul>
      </article>
    </div>
  );
};


const Tree = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <li>{data.name}</li>
      {data.children &&
        data.children.map((child) => {
          return <Tree key={child.name} data={child} />;
        })}
    </>
  );
};

export default TreeView;
```

But now I'm stuck with the ability to actually hide the kids by clicking or presenting them by clicking in the correct order ... I would love to help

this is data :

```
{
  "type": "directory",
  "name": "Kokoapps exercise project",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "directory",
      "name": "Group A",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "directory",
          "name": "Group A-1",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "directory",
              "name": "Group A-1-1",
              "children": [
                { "type": "file", "name": "file1.txt" },
                { "type": "file", "name": "file2.txt" },
                { "type": "file", "name": "file3.txt" }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "file1.txt"
            },
            {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "file2.txt"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "directory",
          "name": "Group A-2",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "file3.txt"
            },
            {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "file4.txt"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "file1.txt"
        },
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "file2.txt"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "directory",
      "name": "Group B",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "directory",
          "name": "Group B-1",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "file1.txt"
            },
            {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "file2.txt"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "directory",
          "name": "Group B-2",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "file3.txt"
            },
            {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "file4.txt"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "file1.txt"
        },
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "file2.txt"
        },
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "file3.txt"
        },
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "file4.txt"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the onClick handler to your tree element and keep a track whether the children are visible or not. Your onClick handler than can toggle the visibility of your children. Something like this should work:

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-chaplygin-9fdb3b?file=/src/App.js:63-68

Comment: tnx so much!!! can u please help with the tree node like this? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp

Comment: do you mean nested? You just need to add ```ul``` tag to wrap the list. I updated the code.